# JSON.parse doesn't produce proper arrays of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I try to pass my string below

> {"1":{"11":{"cityid":1,"bpid":11,"name":"Golden Mile
>   Tower","time":"+00:00","sbpid":50043}},"2":{"34":{"cityid":2,"bpid":34,"name":"KL
>   Sentral","time":"+00:00","sbpid":50040}},"8":{"244":{"cityid":8,"bpid":244,"name":"Taman
>   Sri Puteri","time":"+00:00","sbpid":50042}}}

```
console.log(JSON.parse(str))
```

It doesn't become what I expect like below

[image]

Any idea why??

Comment: Your string can't be converted to your image using pure json parser.

Comment: It doesn't parse to an array with 3 elements - it parses it to an object with three properties because that's what the encoded data is.

Comment: @Andy what shoud i do to achieve the result which is shown in the image?

Answer (score 1):

It woun't produce correct array, because you don't have it.

You have `Object` not `Array`

This is array, cause it starts from index 1:

```
 {
   "1":{"11":{"cityid":1,"bpid":11,"name":"Golden Mile Tower","time":"+00:00","sbpid":50043}},
   "2":{"34":{"cityid":2,"bpid":34,"name":"KL Sentral","time":"+00:00","sbpid":50040}},
   "8":{"244":{"cityid":8,"bpid":244,"name":"Taman Sri Puteri","time":"+00:00","sbpid":50042}}
}
```

and this is array :

```
[
    {"11":{"cityid":1,"bpid":11,"name":"Golden Mile Tower","time":"+00:00","sbpid":50043}},
    {"34":{"cityid":2,"bpid":34,"name":"KL Sentral","time":"+00:00","sbpid":50040}},
    {"244":{"cityid":8,"bpid":244,"name":"Taman Sri Puteri","time":"+00:00","sbpid":50042}}
]
```

---

For converting `Object` to `Array` use loop, like :

```
var arr = [];
for( var a in your_object ){
   arr.push(a);
}
```

Comment: so i have to convert object to array?

Comment: It means that your backend works incorrect or you can work with object or you can convert it to array via loop

Comment: No I grab from the DOM, it has to be like that.

Comment: @Jennifer I had a typo, try now. jcubic - thx

Comment: It doesn't work at all ,see this https://jsfiddle.net/m5jbh8so/

Comment: @Jennifer I told about converting `Object` to `Array` and not `String` to `Array` => https://jsfiddle.net/m5jbh8so/1/

Comment: ur fildde doesn't show correct result, open the console and check

Comment: @Jennifer check updated fiddle. It looks like in your question. => https://jsfiddle.net/m5jbh8so/2/

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse will parse the string only so you are providing the object so it will not parse the object . so wrap your object with single quotes .

I have added the single quote in start and last . now you can check . it will return array .

JSON.parse('{"1":{"11":{"cityid":1,"bpid":11,"name":"Golden Mile     Tower","time":"+00:00","sbpid":50043}},"2":{"34":{"cityid":2,"bpid":34,"name":"KL Sentral","time":"+00:00","sbpid":50040}},"8":{"244":{"cityid":8,"bpid":244,"name":"Taman Sri Puteri","time":"+00:00","sbpid":50042}}}');